# Why do my results show small deviations from expected values?

Tags: list-manipulation

```
Table[StringForm["p=`1`", i], {i, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05}]
(*  
  {p=0.05`, p=0.1`, p=0.15000000000000002`, p=0.2`, p=0.25`, p=0. 30000000000000004`, 
   p=0.35000000000000003`, p=0.4`, p=0.45`, p=0.5`}
*)
```

Why do the results show small deviations from the expected numbers `{..., 0.15, ..., 0.30, ...}`?

Comment: I (kind of) translated your question this time. But the site's language is English.

Comment: I believe the fundamental reason is that with fixed precision, floating point arithmetic -- on a machine that has to translate into binary and then back into decimal -- you get machine representational error of 1/10 and then: `0.05 + 0.05 + 0.05 // FullForm` gives `0.15000000000000002`.

Comment: What do you mean by exact number, did you mean 0.1500000000000002?

Comment: By exact number, i call 0.15, for example

Comment: Murray, how can i put in the result 0.15?

Comment: `Table[StringForm["p=`1`", N@i], {i, 5/100, 5/10, 5/100}]?

Comment: But now the result is p=0.15`, how can i remove the `?

Comment: And why in: Table[i, {i, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05}] the result is {0.05,0.1,0.15,0.2,0.25,0.3,0.35,0.4,0.45,0.5} and no {...,0.15000000000000002`,...}

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `Table["p= " <> ToString[i], {i, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05}]`

Comment: [This tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html), which is part of [overview of numbers and their forms](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumbersOverview.html), might be helpful explaining the ` and the representation of numbers.  [This tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OutputFormatsForNumbers.html) explains further output formats.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for may be

```
Table["p=" <> ToString @ NumberForm[i, 2], {i, 0.05, 0.5, 0.05}]
```

> {"p=0.05", "p=0.1", "p=0.15", "p=0.2", "p=0.25", "p=0.3", "p=0.35",
>   "p=0.4", "p=0.45", "p=0.5"}

This is the simplest way I can think of that produces output with numbers formatted in the way you request.